# issue with variable names including dots

Tags: r, dataframe

There is something I don't understand when calling dataframes column names.
For example:

```
x1<- data.frame(a.variable=c('1','2','3'), b.variable=c('10','20','30'))
x1$a.variable 
# returns [1] 1 2 3 which makes sense
```

However, the line below doesn't make sense to me as the column "a" doesn't exists.

```
x1$a
# returns [1] 1 2 3
```

Could someone help me understand how to avoid that issue? Thanks!

Comment: `$` does partial matching, try `x1[["a"]]` instead.

Comment: @markus Thanks a lot! This works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioned behavior describes one important difference between `$` and `[[`. `$` does partial matching, and `[[` does not (by default). This can be controlled however using the `exact` argument, see `` help(`[`) ``:

```
x1[["a"]]
# NULL

x1[["a", exact = FALSE]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```